# OpenVPN to SMB mount on Ubuntu extremely slow (10+ seconds to run ls)

Tags: mount, samba, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying Linux out as my desktop. I routinely use OpenVPN and from Windows this is no problem. The connection over the VPN sits around 1MB/s which is more than enough for the typical document editing I do. I usually mount a share and then open that in Visual Studio Code.

I'm doing the same thing on Ubuntu but the share is extremely slow. Running an `ls` hangs for seconds before returning, changing directories in VSCode takes 10s of seconds, and I haven't actually been able to get VSCode to create a file.

I have it open at the path: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=<server_ip>,share=<share_name>`

Has anyone seen this and fixed it? Any suggestions on troubleshooting as far as figuring out exactly where the latency is?

Note: I have pulled out my Windows laptop and everything works as expected. Instant response, no lag, etc so I am highly confident the problem is OS side.

Answer (score 2):

gvfs ( gio ) has a lot of overhead. CIFS is controlled by the Linux kernel and is more efficient so you might want to see if cifs results in better performance.

Make sure a cifs helper program is installed:

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```

Create a mount point - for example:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ServerShare
```

Then do a temporary mount using cifs:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<server_ip>/<share_name> /mnt/ServerShare -o username=XXXXX,password=YYYYY,uid=1000
```

The XXXXX / YYYYY parameters are what the server is expecting and 1000 is your ubuntu uid number - you can also use your ubuntu user name ... like uid=morbius.

If that works better you can have this automount in fstab if you want.

If it doesn't improve things you can unmount with a: `sudo umount /mnt/ServerShare`

Comment: I'll give that a shot this afternoon - that's what I normally do but since this isn't a lab and I'm using passwords I care about I had forgotten how to securely mount it such that my password wasn't just sitting around in /etc/fstab. I'll go look it up this afternoon